# How to extract value with different number of indexes in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Example:

Original

```
A105
AA105
AAA105
AAA1105
```

Values wanted:

```
A
AA
AAA
AAA1
```

Basically the entire index of a Cell minus 3.

Not the best explanation, but hope you get the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an unused column to the right try one of these,

```
=left(a2, max(len(a2)-3, 1))
=iferror(left(a2, len(a2)-3), a2)
```

Assuming that your data does not stray away from the examples, you would not require the [MAX](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/max-function-f7bec1eb-9c66-489a-9166-51d2c9d19333) or the [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) function. They are only included for worst-case-scenarios.